# How to find cpu usage of a process of which i have the pid in android ndk

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, cpu, proc

i am to get the pid of the process and i want to calculate the cpu usage of the process of which i have the pid in android ndk.i am a newbie to ndk.
Anyone knows how to do that,any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/esDbHDzJidc) I found that it's impossible to get that information on Android. And also I used many task managers on Android and none of them didn't provide such data (they show only memory usage).

**Update:**

Looks like your question is duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486570/memory-and-cpu-per-process-android).

So all you need to do is to analyze file `/proc/<pid>/stat` to get CPU usage.

**Update #2:**

From source [Android top.c](http://source-android.frandroid.com/system/core/toolbox/top.c) I found how to get process usage in function `print_procs`:

```
proc->delta_time * 100 / total_delta_time
```

Comment: thanks for the reply that for the reason i am asking it in ndk..not in java

Comment: It is impossible programatically - doesn't metter if it's java or c++.

Comment: thanks for the link they only describe how to get the utime & stime that i have already calculated

Comment: thanks for the link hope so that this help me....i will try to figure out how to find cpu usage i try'ed earlier to make a function that accept the pid as argument and return cpu usage but unfortunately i was only able to get the stime and utime

Comment: @chiv can u pls tell how u have achieved your task i m also facing same issue but in android there is no way to find this how can i find using read/stat /proc by passing process id